# Azure Service Management in Python - ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2084)

Tags: python, azure, ssl, python-3.x

I have created a .cer file and uploaded that to Azure Management Panel.  I created this using Administrator: Command Prompt.

```
makecert -sky exchange -r -n "CN=AzureCertificate" -pe -a sha1 -len 2048 -ss My "AzureCertificate.cer"
```

This is my code:

```
from azure import *
from azure.servicemanagement import *

subscription_id = '<MY SUBSCRIPTION ID>'
cert_path = r'C:\AzureCertificate.cer'

sms = ServiceManagementService(subscription_id,cert_path)

result = sms.list_locations()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    result = sms.list_locations()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\azure-0.8.1-py3.3.egg\azure\servicemanagement\servicemanagementservice.py", line 939, in list_locations
    Locations)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\azure-0.8.1-py3.3.egg\azure\servicemanagement\servicemanagementclient.py", line 108, in _perform_get
    response = self._perform_request(request)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\azure-0.8.1-py3.3.egg\azure\servicemanagement\servicemanagementclient.py", line 95, in _perform_request
    resp = self._filter(request)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\azure-0.8.1-py3.3.egg\azure\http\httpclient.py", line 182, in perform_request
    connection = self.get_connection(request)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\azure-0.8.1-py3.3.egg\azure\http\httpclient.py", line 143, in get_connection
    host, int(port), cert_file=self.cert_file)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1186, in __init__
    context.load_cert_chain(cert_file, key_file)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2063)
```

Is anyone able to diagnose this error, I haven't found much help online.

Comment: I believe that's a Python error, and not an OpenSSL error that has trickled up. OpenSSL does not have an `ssl.c` file.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set cert_path to this:
    `cert_path = 'CURRENT_USER\\my\\AzureCertificate'`

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-python-how-to-use-service-management/

Open SSL certificates as described in the 'Management certificates on Mac/Linux' section in the above link are now supported on Windows.  The way it detects if it should use httplib or winhttp is by the cert_path.  If it's a path to a file, it will use httplib (open ssl certificate).  If not, it will use winhttp.